# Getting IP geolocation

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, ip, ip-address

I have a database that has a "users" table where i have a last_login_ip field for each user  that stores the IP address of the device where they last visited my website. I'd like to know country, city and state of all my visitors. I've been investigating IP addresses theory but i can't find a way to get this information aside of websites that already have this service, the problem with these websites is that i have to insert each IP address individually and i can't do that to 4000+ users. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: That's likely going to be the only way. Many services accept larger amounts of data (=requests), you'll just usually have to pay them

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is off-topic, but since you're here: [ipinfodb.com](http://ipinfodb.com) offer a free service, and [MaxMind](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) offer a downloadable database of IP locations you can use if you provide an attribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of APIs to do that. Like for example this one very simple :

http://www.hostip.info/use.html

An example of code in php using this API would be

```
<?php
$ip = "replace_with_your_ip";
// Get country
$data = file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=".$ip);

//Get other location infos
$data = file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/?ip=".$ip);
?>
```

It can be more convenient in some case to use Javascript and make Ajax calls on these URLs.